# How to handle one-time event across components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck trying to determine the best way to trigger a one-time event (like an animation) from one component to be executed in another.

**For example:**

I have 3 buttons. When I click one button, I want its neighbouring button to flash/pulse once.

**Here's what I've whipped up:**

When a button is clicked, a container passes the a `true` clicked flag to the proper sibling. The container then immediately clears the flag (after the animation is complete).

Rough implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/869etunw/1/

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
    state = {}

  render() {
    const {pulse} = this.state
    return <div>
      <Button id={1} pulse={pulse == 3} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      <Button id={2} pulse={pulse == 1} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      <Button id={3} pulse={pulse == 2} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    </div>
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log('pulse ' + id)
    this.setState({
        pulse: id,
    }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('stop')
        this.setState({
        pulse: null,
      })
      }, 500)
    })
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div 
    style={{
        display:'inline-block', 
      padding: '8px 16px', 
      background: 'red', 
      margin: 8, 
      cursor: 'pointer',
      transition: '.5s ease all',
        border: this.props.pulse ? '3px solid green' : '0px solid transparent',
    }}
    onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.id)}
    >Hello</div>
  }
}
```

Is that the proper way to do such a thing? Are there better ways to handle this case with a state manager like Redux or Flux?

[image: Here's a gif if you don't want to open the jsfiddle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the right to comment. I wanted to ask for more details. But anyhow I came up with a solution that might help you. You don't need to use redux or flux to achieve it. You can do this directly using states.

This is the minimalistic change that you need to do to get the proper animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/anujladia/g2601r58/

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    const {pulse} = this.state
    return <div>
      <Button id={1} pulse={this.state.pulse === 1} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      <Button id={2} pulse={this.state.pulse == 2} onClick={this.handleClick} />
      <Button id={3} pulse={this.state.pulse == 3} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    </div>
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log('pulse ' + id)
    this.setState({
        pulse: id,
    }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('stop')
        this.setState({
        pulse: null,
      })
      }, 500)
    })
  }
}
```

I just changed the value of pulse prop that was being sent to Button Component.

This might be another way to do it.
https://jsfiddle.net/anujladia/3j0n2pwy/

Hope so this resolves your problem.

Comment: Hi Anuj, I actually want a sibling to pulse when a button is clicked like in my example. But really, I wanted to know if the sequential `setState` like in your `onClick` handler is the best way to do that.