# Stop API call from 2nd component (same component) on render - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-native

I'm trying to create a reusable `SelectDropdown` component for our app (and this `SelectDropdown` will be used across the platform not just from this page), and wanted to know if it's possible to stop the API call on the 2nd **same** component when the API call is currently ongoing from the 1st component

`dropdown-with-option.tsx`:

```
const DropdownWithOptions= (props) => {
  const [ options, setOptions ] = useState([]);

  const syncOptions = (items) => {
    setOptions(items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options || options.length === 0) {
      // api call
      getSelections().then(syncOptions);
    }
  }, []);

  return <Dropdown options={options} {...props}/>
};
```

`page.tsx`:

```
const Page = () => {
  return <>
     <DropdownWithOptions/> // - first component should run the api call
     <DropdownWithOptions/> // - second same component should not run the api call
  </>
}
```

I have no idea at this time if it's possible or not

I'm already using `Context` but no idea how am I going to tell the second component to wait for the `state` / API call to finish, as far as I know, both Components will have the same `state` upon render and it will try to do the same thing (call API) at init, so having `isDoneCallingAPI` state will not work in this case and I don't want to go and used `Observables` at this point.

any answer or comment will be really helpful

Comment: Although a click event and not a load this is a similar concept perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69665544/125981

Comment: Here is another similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/55946616/125981

Answer (score 0):

Make one central loading state and pass that state as prop to this dropdown component. Before calling the API, check if loading is false then call the API otherwise do not call the API.